# Term for wordplay: frictionless trade vs tradeless friction

Tags: terminology

> *Brexit promise: frictionless trade. Brexit reality: tradeless friction*

This often appears in the internet discussions on Brexit. Is there a more specialized term to describe this specific kind of wordplay?

Comment: [Antimetabole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimetabole)

Comment: @GarethRees. That one word Comment should be turned into an Answer (even if it's only one word).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Baldick's and Cuddon's dictionaries of literary terms, this is an **antimetabole**. Cuddon's definition goes as follows:

> The repetition of words in successive clauses, in reverse grammatical order.

Cuddon provides the following example from Samuel Johnson's [*The Rambler*](http://www.jacklynch.net/Texts/rambler156.html) (156, emphasis mine):

> It ought to be the first endeavour of a writer to distinguish nature from custom, or that which is **established** because it is **right**, from that which is **right** only because it is **established**; (...)

Baldick points out that antimetabole is a sub-type of **chiasmus** and gives the following example:

> All for one, and one for all.

The [Algemeen letterkundig lexicon](https://dbnl.org/tekst/dela012alge01_01/dela012alge01_01_02007.php) (in Dutch) points out that the antimetabole expresses an [antithesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antithesis) by means of a chiasm. The phrases "frictionless trade" and "tradeless friction" are antithetical; so are the terms "promise" and "reality" in the context of the given quote.

---

References:

- Baldick, Chris: *The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Literary Terms*. Second edition. Oxford University Press, 2001.
- Cuddon, J. A.: *The Penguin Dictionary of Literary Terms and Literary Theory*. Third edition. Penguin 1992.
- dbnl: [Algemeen letterkundig lexicon](https://dbnl.org/tekst/dela012alge01_01/index.php) (containing 4,600 terms, in Dutch).